# Toggle Switch doesn't save is state when i scroll down the view and return up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, toggle

In this view i have a table with cells composed by one label and one toggle.
If I try to change the state of this toggle it works, but if I scroll the view and than I returned to the toggle changed I found it in the previous state.
I have never worked whit this object so i don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you use `UITableView` or just `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Is a tableView with more of 20 cells so to view all of them i have to scroll the table

Comment: Table view cells are reused. You have to set all UI elements to a defined state in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, that means if there is a condition in an `if` clause you have to add an `else` clause to do the opposite.

Comment: You will find your answer by [reviewing these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uitableview+uiswitch+scroll).

Answer (score 0):

You use 'UITableView', and all cells reuses for performance optimisation. You need check changing of `UISwitch` state and save it in your model. When your cell will reuse, you need to set saved state to `UISwitch` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.